# Different behaviour of WebAudio API on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-audio-api

I'm doing a sound player with a spectrum visualizer. On Firefox works very well but in Google Chrome I'm getting problems. I came from this question I made the other day [My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612763/html5-audio-gets-louder-after-pausing-then-playing-again)

On Firefox I can go forward or go previous on the track list all the times I want without a problem, but in Google Chrome I get this error when I press "next/previous"

```
Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'BaseAudioContext': 
HTMLMediaElement already connected previously to a different MediaElementSourceNode.
```

I don't know why Google Chrome complains and Firefox doesn't. The code of the visualizer it's:

```
 function visualizer(audio) {
    closeAudioContext = true;
    let src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);  // Here fails on Google Chrome
    let analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    src.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    analyser.fftSize = 2048;

    let bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;

    let dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

    let WIDTH = ctx.canvas.width;
    let HEIGHT = ctx.canvas.height;

    let barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 1.5;
    let barHeight;
    let x = 0;

    let color = randomColor();

    function renderFrame() {
      requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
      x = 0;
      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

      for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        barHeight = dataArray[i];

        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
        x += barWidth + 1;

      }
    }

    renderFrame();
  }
```

And after press the "next/previous" button I do immediately:

```
if (closeAudioContext && context !== undefined) {
      context.close();
}
context = new AudioContext();
```

And then:

```
visualizer(audio);
musicPlay();
```

So my question is, why in Firefox the audio player works fine but in Google Chrome crashes?

I'm using [Bowser](https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser) to check what browser the user is using because as the new policy of Chrome to mute all sounds if its activated the autoplay (in this case I set the autoPlay to false and if the user press play the sound it's not muted). So, if I have to make a different code for Google Chrome I can make an "if" with that code.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in Chrome; you can't cannot attach an `HTMLMediaElement` to another `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`.  But since you close the context and create a new one, that's another different bug in Chrome.

Comment: Can't seem to find the bug number for the first issue, though.  It would be great if you filed an issue for the second bug at crbug.com/new with your repro case.

Comment: Done! id = 851310